# Template Variadic argument deduction from sibling argument

Tags: c++, c++20

I have this simple templated structure:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
struct Packet  {
   void DoSmth(Args... args){}
};

//usage
struct Packet1Model{};
struct Packet1: Packet<Packet1Model, int,float ,int>{

};
```

Is there a way in c++ to have a function that takes as a template argument
an `typename T` and an other typename pack `typename... Args` and have the pack deduced from `T`?

Better explanation:

```
//Main ideea
template<typename PacketType, typename... Args>
void Func(Args... args) {//is there a way for this Args... pack to be "DEDUCED" as the Args... pack of PacketType::DoSmth() ?
    PacketType myLocalPacketType;

    myLocalT.DoSmth(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// Wanted effect
//...
{
    //eg. for Packet1 -> Args pack is (int, float, int)
    Func<Packet1>(2, 2.0f, 3);
}
//...
```

This is the main ideea, i can do any modifications as long as the broad interface is the same.

Could partial specialization achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are they needed to be deduced? If they are wrong, it will simply not compile. There are C++17 deductions guides that might maybe help, but in general arguments cannot be deduced based on the body.

Comment: @DavisHerring is't this the case for `std::forward` -> `Packet2: Packet<Mode2, std::string&&>` so i can do `Func<Packet2>(std::move(myMovedString))`?

Comment: @BalanNarcis: That does work, although you can also just use `static_cast<Args>(args)...` in this case; I assumed from your example that object types were intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along these lines with a wrapper class (and a trick to obtain the relevant base class for the template argument):

```
namespace detail {
  template<class,class> struct Wrap;
  template<class PacketType,class T,class ...TT>
  struct Wrap<PacketType,Packet<T,TT...>> {
    void Func(TT ...tt) {
      PacketType myLocalT;
      myLocalT.DoSmth(tt...);
    }
  };

  template<class ...TT> Packet<TT...> UpCast(Packet<TT...>*); // not defined
}

template<class P>
using Wrap=detail::Wrap<P,decltype(UpCast(static_cast<P*>(nullptr)))>;

void client() {
  Wrap<Packet1>::Func(2, 2.0f, 3);
}
```

Of course, doing this loses the possibility of **excluding** this particular `Func` from overload resolution because the parameters don't match, which would seem to be the main advantage over a trivial "optimistic wrapper" (that would encounter a non-SFINAE error given such a mismatch):

```
template<class P,class ...AA>
void Func(AA &&...aa) {
  P myLocalT;
  myLocalT.DoSmth(std::forward<AA>(aa)...);
}
```

Comment: Simply put there isn't a more direct way to do what i asked. Hopefully next generations of C++ will have some sort of guided template argument deduction. Thanks.

Comment: @BalanNarcis: The problem is that packs aren’t first class, so we can’t just write `template<class T> void Func(get_the_pack<T>...) {…}`.  There are in fact proposals to allow packs to be introduced more easily, but I’m not immediately sure if any of them cover this case.